# Download more than 500 mb size video or image file from server to sdcard in android?

Tags: android, download, background-process, imagedownload

i am trying to download images and videos from server to sdcard for offline play.
but problem is if image and video size is morethan 35 mb than video is not dowloaded and app is crash.

my image size is upto 50mb and video size is 50 to 500mb most video size is 300mb so how can i dowload the images and video related  to this size.

here i put my code so you can check it

> HomeActivity.java

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity 
{   
    ProgressDialog progressdialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> myplaylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    String filename="";
    int count=0;

    PowerManager pm;
    WakeLock wl;

    ImageView imageview;
    VideoView videoview;

    int length=0;
    int i=0; 
    boolean video=false;

    private final int TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = 10000;//5sec
    private final int TIMEOUT_SOCKET = 10000;//30sec

    @SuppressLint("Wakelock")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        imageview=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        videoview=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoview);

        pm = (PowerManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                getApplicationContext().POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "WakeLockOn");
        wl.acquire();



        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("image","http://pr83.webofficeserver.info/img/sliderimg/original/1387205637Desertkp123-232.jpg");
        map.put("type","video");
        myplaylist.add(map);

        HashMap<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map2.put("image","http://pr83.webofficeserver.info/img/thumbnails/video/dummy.mov");
        map2.put("type","image");
        myplaylist.add(map2);

        HashMap<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map3.put("image","http://pr83.webofficeserver.info/img/sliderimg/original/1387206137planet-earth-in-space.jpg");
        map3.put("type","video");
        myplaylist.add(map3);

        HashMap<String, String> map4 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map4.put("image","http://pr83.webofficeserver.info/img/thumbnails/video/BrandHi-240.mp4");
        map4.put("type","video");
        myplaylist.add(map4);


        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(myplaylist.get(count).get("image").toString());

    }

    // For Download File From Url

    public class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {

        private final int TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = 10000;//5sec
        private final int TIMEOUT_SOCKET = 10000;//30sec

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            progressdialog=ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this, "","Please Wait");


        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {

                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                new File(root + "/montorwerbung").mkdirs();


                            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);    
                            Uri u = Uri.parse(f_url[0]);
                            File f1 = new File("" + u);
                            filename=f1.getName();

                            File file = new File(root + "/montorwerbung" , filename);

                            Log.e("File Download Sdcard Filename","--->"+filename);
                            Log.e("File Download Sdcard Path","--->"+file.toString());
                            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                            //Open a connection to that URL.
                            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

                            //this timeout affects how long it takes for the app to realize there's a connection problem
                             //  ucon.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
                              // ucon.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_SOCKET);

                            //Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                            // uses 3KB download buffer
                            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                            BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 1024);

                            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            byte[] buff = new byte[10 * 1024];

                            //Read bytes (and store them) until there is nothing more to read(-1)
                            int len;
                            while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1)
                            {
                                outStream.write(buff,0,len);
                            }

                            //clean up
                            outStream.flush();
                            outStream.close();
                            inStream.close();




            } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.e("Download file frp, server Exception", "Exception : "
                        + e.getMessage(), e); 
                //Log.e("Error: ",+e.printStackTrace());
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
        {
            if(progressdialog.isShowing())
            {   
                progressdialog.dismiss();

            }

            Log.e("Count: ","----->"+count);

            count++;
            if(count<myplaylist.size())
            {
                new DownloadFileFromURL2().execute(myplaylist.get(count).get("image").toString());

            }
            else
            {
                wl.release();
                Log.e("No More Downloads","--->");
            }

        }

    }
class DownloadFileFromURL2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> 
    {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() 
        {
            progressdialog=ProgressDialog.show(HomeActivity.this, "","Please Wait");
        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            int count;
            try {

                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                new File(root + "/montorwerbung").mkdirs();

                            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);    

                            Uri u = Uri.parse(f_url[0]);
                            File f1 = new File("" + u);
                            filename=f1.getName();

                            File file = new File(root + "/montorwerbung" , filename);

                            Log.e("File Download Sdcard Filename","--->"+filename);
                            Log.e("File Download Sdcard Path","--->"+file.toString());
                            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                             //Open a connection to that URL.
                            URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

                            //Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
                            // uses 3KB download buffer
                            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
                            BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 10);

                            FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                            byte[] buff = new byte[10 * 1024];

                            //Read bytes (and store them) until there is nothing more to read(-1)
                            int len;
                            while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1)
                            {
                                outStream.write(buff,0,len);
                            }

                            //clean up
                            outStream.flush();
                            outStream.close();
                            inStream.close();



            } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                Log.e("Download file frp, server Exception", "Exception : "
                        + e.getMessage(), e); 
                //Log.e("Error: ",+e.printStackTrace());
            }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) 
        {
            if(progressdialog.isShowing())
            {   
                progressdialog.dismiss();

            }

            count++;

            Log.e("Count: ","----->"+count);
            if(count<myplaylist.size())
            {
                new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(myplaylist.get(count).get("image").toString());
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                wl.release();
                Log.e("No More Downloads 2","--->");
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Compressed it best way because size is more> 50 MB

Comment: means admin upload video and image on server at that time compress video and images and than uplaod ?

Comment: yup exactly like `WhatsApp`.

Comment: is there any other way it is possible

Comment: @Mahesh hey have you solved the your problem ?